# Perl CGI code bug

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi

hello there is exploit in this code ? can attacker bypass this and upload other file or webshell ?
or it's secure

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;

$q = new CGI;
if (defined($q->param('Head'))) {
  print $q->header(-type=>'image/bmp');
  open(HEAD,"head".$q->param('Head'));
  open(HAIR,"hair".$q->param('Hair'));
  open(NOSE,"nose".$q->param('Nose'));
  open(MOUTH,"mouth".$q->param('Mouth'));
  open(EYES,"eyes".$q->param('Eyes'));

  while (read(HEAD,$headb,1)) {
    read(HAIR,$hairb,1);
    read(NOSE,$noseb,1);
    read(MOUTH,$mouthb,1);
    read(EYES,$eyesb,1);
    print (chr (ord($headb)&ord($hairb)&ord($noseb)&ord($mouthb)&ord($eyesb)));
  }
}
else {
  print $q->header;

  print $q->start_html(-title=>"Hello wolrd test",-script=>{'src'=>'/js.js'},-style=>{'src'=>'/css.css'});
  print $q->div(
   $q->h1("Avatar Generator"),
   $q->p("make your face !"),
   "<video><source src='https://zippy.gfycat.com/DesertedEasygoingArabianwildcat.webm'></source></video><canvas></canvas>",
   $q->start_form(-id=>"frm",-method=>"POOP",-action=>"#",-onchange=>"loadImage()"),
   $q->br(),
   $q->table(
    $q->Tr($q->td([$q->b("Head"),$q->input({-name=>"Head",-type=>'range',-min=>1,-max=>4})])),
    $q->Tr($q->td([$q->b("Hair"),$q->input({-name=>"Hair",-type=>'range',-min=>0,-max=>2})])),
    $q->Tr($q->td([$q->b("Nose"),$q->input({-name=>"Nose",-type=>'range',-min=>1,-max=>3})])),
    $q->Tr($q->td([$q->b("Mouth"),$q->input({-name=>"Mouth",-type=>'range',-min=>1,-max=>3})])),
    $q->Tr($q->td([$q->b("Eyes"),$q->input({-name=>"Eyes",-type=>'range',-min=>1,-max=>3})]))
   ),
   $q->end_form
  );
  open SELF, "index.cgi";
  print $q->comment("DEBUG SOURCE\n".do { local $/; <SELF> });
  print $q->end_html();
}
```

and the JS CODE http://pastebin.com/JvwQkVMT

any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Never accept arbitrary file names from a user other than the process's owner.**

By passing the same file name for all five fields, a client can fetch any file your server can access.

But that's nothing compared to passing the following for one of the fields:

```
rm -rf / |
```

Comment: Hmm oky anything else. ?

Comment: No. The entirety of the code that deals with user inputs is broken. It's literally impossible to be any more broken than this.